# Jdo error duplicate key

Tags: java, jdo

i have 2 classes A, B.

- Class A:  [class A](http://pastebin.com/6EnV43ru)
- Class B: [class B](http://pastebin.com/MR4h24QM)

This is class Main:

```
public class Main
{ 
    static PersistenceManagerFactory pmf ;

    static Transaction tx1 ;
    static PersistenceManager pm1 ;

    public Main(){

       pmf = JDOHelper.getPersistenceManagerFactory("datanucleus.properties");

    }

    public static void testB(B b){

        pm1 = pmf.getPersistenceManager();
        tx1=pm1.currentTransaction();

        try {
            tx1.begin();


            B bb=b;

            pm1.makePersistent(bb);


            tx1.commit();

         } finally {
             if (tx1.isActive())
             {
                 tx1.rollback();
             }
             pm1.close();
         }
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {

        Main n=new Main();

        String id="4";


        A a=new A(id,"prova");

        B b2=new B("4a",a);
        B b3=new B("5a",a);  //// error HERE ////////////////////////////////

        Main.testB(b2);
        Main.testB(b3);
    }
}
```

When I run the Main class I get an error, namely:

```
Exception in thread "main" javax.jdo.JDODataStoreException: Insert of object "B@95973d" using statement "INSERT INTO `B` (`ID`,`IDR`) VALUES (?,?)" failed : Duplicate entry '4' for key 'PRIMARY'
at org.datanucleus.api.jdo.NucleusJDOHelper.getJDOExceptionForNucleusException(NucleusJDOHelper.java:421)
at org.datanucleus.api.jdo.JDOPersistenceManager.jdoMakePersistent(JDOPersistenceManager.java:735)
at org.datanucleus.api.jdo.JDOPersistenceManager.makePersistent(JDOPersistenceManager.java:755)
at Main.testB(Main.java:167)
at Main.main(Main.java:322)
```

As I understand it, in the Main class, specifically in this line of code:

```
    A a=new A(id,"prova");

    B b2=new B("4a",a);
    B b3=new B("5a",a);  //// error HERE ////////////////////////////////

    Main.testB(b2);
    Main.testB(b3);
```

I get the error "Duplicate entry '4 'for key' PRIMARY '"

In Table B, I want to insert multiple values ​​for a PK of table A, how can I fix it?

Comment: Not quite enough information here.  Can you provide code for your A and B Classes, and verify which version of JDO you are using.  You may want to adjust your code for Main to describe all your particular use of JDO (imports, how version of JDO, any javaz.jdo.persistenceManagerFactoryClass etc.) Imports appear to include:  javax.jdo.JDOHelper; import javax.jdo.PersistenceManager;     import javax.jdo.PersistenceManagerFactory; import javax.jdo.Transaction;

Comment: @ErstwhileIII The codes of the classes A and B are in their link! The version of JDO is 3.1. The packages are imported into the Main class: import javax.jdo.PersistenceManager;
import javax.jdo.PersistenceManagerFactory;
import javax.jdo.Query;
import javax.jdo.JDOHelper;
import javax.jdo.Transaction;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the "A" object is in "transient" state when you persist the B, hence it will try to persist a new A each time. If instead you persist the A and then **detach** it (pm.detachCopy, when the object is marked as detachable) and set the A field of the B to that, it will work. Any JDO docs has references to detaching and object states. Create the A like this

```
pm.currentTransaction().begin();
A a = new A(id,"prova");
a = pm.makePersistent(a);
A detachedA = pm.detachCopy(a);
pm.currentTransaction().commit();
```

then use "detachedA" with the persist of the B's.

Comment: Could you kindly give an example on how to set the method "testB"? thanks

Comment: As already said, it is the object A that is wrong, not that method. The A that you use has to be in DETACHED state, and I told you how to get an object A in detached state

Comment: The method testA the I changed to this: http://pastebin.com/T4MTcPEp while in the Main class: http://pastebin.com/VGMCmzit  but I get:   Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
 at B.<init>(B.java:63)
 at Main.main(Main.java:311)
to the constructor of B precisely: http://pastebin.com/sfd5xRfv    where am I wrong?

Comment: An NPE in your own code ought to be easy for you to debug what you've done wrong. Your code is nothing like the code I posted above. Good luck

Comment: deleting the annotation (@NotPersistent) in A class on the field "List<B> a;" I do not get the NullPointerException more, but now I get: "Insert of object" A@1496569th "using statement" INSERT INTO `A` (`PROVA`, `ID`) VALUES (?,?) "failed: Duplicate entry '1a'for key' PRIMARY '" It may be because of how I made the constructor of B? check because the class "A" to the variable of type "A" and probably every time it creates a new one? http://pastebin.com/D4ch8ep3  I do not know what to do! :(

Comment: So you haven't bothered making your class Detachable (like I said to do in the answer). This is in all JDO docs, so i strongly suggest that you read them.